# How to change text in table for specific adjoining column?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using VBA macro for WORD in order to replace all "[" chars with "".
The macro is **working fine** for replacing all chars within all tables with some color.

How do I **add if statement to make it work only if the Column A contains "Test"**

**Before:**

| Header 1 | [Text |
| --- | --- |
| Test: | **[Text** |

**After:**

| Header 1 | [Text |
| --- | --- |
| Test: | **Text** |

So far I got this and it works fine (But for all table rows and not specific for the "Test" row.

```
Sub FindChar2()

Dim oTbl As Table
Dim stT As Long, enT As Long
Dim stS As Long, enS As Long

With Selection.Find             ' Replacement
    .Text = "["
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With

For Each oTbl In ActiveDocument.Tables

    If oTbl.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(176, 255, 137) Then 
    
        oTbl.Columns(1).Select

        Do While Selection.Find.Execute

            stT = oTbl.Range.Start                    ' table range
            enT = oTbl.Range.End

            stS = Selection.Range.Start               ' found text range
            enS = Selection.Range.End

            If stS < stT Or enS > enT Then Exit Do

            Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
            
        Loop
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    
    End If
    
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 'Test' is the only content in column A (I note your sample has 'Test:), you could use:

```
Sub TblFnd()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table, Rng As Range
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  With Tbl
    If .Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(176, 255, 137) Then
      Set Rng = .Range
      With .Range
        With .Find
          .ClearFormatting
          .Replacement.ClearFormatting
          .Text = "["
          .Forward = True
          .Wrap = wdFindStop
          .Format = False
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
          If .InRange(Rng) Then
            If .Cells(1).ColumnIndex = 2 Then
              If Split(.Cells(1).Row.Cells(1).Range.Text, vbCr)(0) = "Test" Then .Text = ""
            End If
          Else
            Exit Do
          End If
          .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
      End With
    End If
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @macropod, first of all, thanks it looks great. I think I wasn't clear enough (My mistake). I got a few tables and an unknown number of rows in each table. In each table, there are only 2 columns, first for headers and second with data. I want to locate the row in the first column (Headers) with the exact header name "Test" and make the "[" char replaces with "" in the cell from the right.

Comment: In Word, the term 'Header' applies exclusively to one or more entire rows at the top of the table. See revised code. I've revised your question accordingly also.

Comment: I've got a Compile error: "Method or data member not found"

Comment: "Run-time error 4218: Type mismatch" pointing at the row: `If.InRange(Rng) Then`

Comment: OK, the code working - Thanks!  But instead of deleting only the "[" char at the beginning of the text, it deletes all the text. What should I change?